# Textarea name given back undefined

Tags: php, html, textarea

Getting back `$message` is undefined. I've tried switching `$_POST['message']` to `$_POST['send']`. it works, but for some reason it won't work with the text-area. I even tried to switch the button type from button to submit. It didn't help. This mistake's given me a real headache.

```
<?php
$message = $_POST['message'];
?>

<form action="chat.php" method="POST">
<textarea name="message" id="type" placeholder="Type your message"></textarea>
<input name="send" id="send" type="button" value="send" onclick="sendmsg()"/>
</form>
```

Comment: have you tried isset() and what is sendmsg() is doing

Comment: Give something else in place of type id="type" because type is library keyword.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've remove `sendmessage()` and replace button type to `submit`. Keeping it simple.

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['send'])){
echo "<pre>";
print_r($_POST);
$message = $_POST['message'];
}
?>

<form action="" method="POST">
<textarea name="message" id="msgtype" placeholder="Type your message"></textarea>
<input name="send" id="send" type="submit"/>
</form>
```

Try it. Hope it'll work.

Comment: returns array() but the undefined problem is still there

Comment: @Bryan: Post your array. Let me check what its returning.

Comment: i copy and pasted what u wrote. it returned Array
(
)


Notice:  Undefined index: message in C:\Users\meansnail24\Desktop\project_w\SocialNetwork\htdocs\Creation\testing100.php on line 4

Comment: Modified the answer. Please check now.

Comment: nvm, i fixed it. i was missing the if(isset($_POST['send']))

Answer (score 1):

Do one thing:

```
print_r($_POST); die;
```

And check whats coming from form . It will help you to find out the problem.

Comment: This is not a solution.

Comment: bt your code doesn't have any error .. so you can check if "message key coming or not "

Answer (score 0):

if you are getting Post in same page .. keep you action blank